# How do I connect NGINX to PostgreSQL for valid virtual host domains?

Tags: database, nginx

I have nginx listening on port 80, and passing requests through to meteor (wraps node.js) on port 3000.

That is pretty easy to do, and I got it working.

However, I want nginx to ONLY process requests for valid virtual host domains. There are going to be lots, so I thought it would make sense to connect NGINX to PostgreSQL and store them there.

I compiled NGINX with this module: http://labs.frickle.com/nginx_ngx_postgres/ to achieve that.

Here is the nginx.conf stanza:

```
http {
    upstream database {
        postgres_server  127.0.0.1 dbname=some_name user=some_user password=some_password;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            postgres_pass     database;
            postgres_query   "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE domain='$http_host'";
            proxy_pass        http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought it was working fine, because I was getting the correct results for 3 test domains I added to the DB. But, then I removed one, and it still worked!

So, clearly, I've configured it wrong. This is a unique enough case, Google is not helping. :(

Anyone done this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `curl '-HHost:\' or 1; -- delete from users'`